# How to get input from Form in angular in to component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to get 2 inputs from HTML with reactive form in Angular to Component.ts file

basically its username and password,

```
                <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Username" formControlName="userName" >
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
                </mat-form-field>
```

to this authRequest,

```
loginForm: FormGroup;
authRequest: any = {
    'userName': 'admin',
    'password': 'admin',
};
```

this is hardcoded here, I want to get userinput dynamically to here,

Comment: Can you explain what exactly your problem is? Why do you have the loginForm declared, but it seems like the authRequest object should hold the information. What should be the case here?

Comment: The "value" are `this.authRequest.value.userName` and `this.authRequest.value.password` or `this.authRequest.get('userName').value` and `this.authRequest.get('password').value`

Comment: Why are you using type `any` for authRequest? Are you assigning completely different value later?

Comment: @FabianStrathaus , I want to get inputs from user userName and Password and  fetch those 2 to the authRequest to pass backend.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two different objects to store your data.
In your HTML, you have to first of all bin to the formGroup like this (I added a button at the bottom so you can `console.log` your values by clicking a button):

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <mat-form-field class="w-100">
    <input matInput placeholder="Username" formControlName="userName" />
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="w-100">
    <input
      matInput
      type="password"
      placeholder="Password"
      formControlName="password"
    />
  </mat-form-field>

</form>

<button mat-button type="button" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Then, in you typescript, you have to define the formGroup accordingly:

```
loginForm = new FormGroup({
  userName: new FormControl(),
  password: new FormControl(),
});

submit() {
  console.log(this.loginForm.value);
}
```